# Heat buildup in Raspberry Pi cases

Tags: hardware

I'm looking to build a nice wood case for my Pi. However, I've noticed that the processor already generates a good deal of heat.

Would putting my Pi in a case cause noticeably higher temperatures? Should I also attach a heatsink?

Comment: Ensuring relatively good airflow would be better than a heatsink, the BCM IC is designed to run at high temperatures without any heatsinks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a Pi in a wooden case (see [New wooden cases for your #RaspberryPi at @ThePiHut](http://www.recantha.co.uk/blog/?p=6159)) and run it 24x7. I believe the key is to ensure good airflow through the case. Remember, if you add heatsinks to the processor (and/or other components), the dissipated heat will still be inside the case.